# Soft question - recommendations concerning basic topics inside rough set theory

Tags: soft-question, alternative-set-theories

(I hope this will be phrased alright, apologies if it isn't, it's my first soft question!) I'm looking into **rough set theory** because it seems like a very interesting concept. I'm still a beginner in the field of set theory and I'm currently expanding my knowledge there as well.

What I'm precisely looking for are maybe some results concerning rough set theory, e.g. some theorems or conclusions that could be a focal point of a presentation(1-2h long let's say). E.g. some basic but useful and somewhat interesting results that would be concluded and proved from the basic definitions, ideas and concepts involving rough set theory, but in a mathematical approach(as in not direct applications, but rather some interesting results from the perspective of formal mathemathics.)

Basically, any smaller, but currently active/fun topic inside rough set theory that doesn't require **too much** (I don't want to come off as lazy, of course I'll delve into it as much as I can, but I'm limited timewise) prior knowledge of rough set theory on its' own, if that makes sense. Anything directly related to rough set theory but maybe stuff like our regular set theory(ZFC let's say) and topology as well.

Also, any specific topic that comes after the basic introduction (but would be attractive to a mathematician) that you would recommend to someone who's just started researching rough set theory would be really awesome!

Thanks in advance!